# What is the best free complete TeX rendering service?

Tags: online, rendering

What is the best free complete TeX rendering service which supports all the packages that a desktop-based TeX distribution supports and is accessible via an API?

I want to generate TeX on the fly without installing TeX on my computer.

Comment: I think the "best" depends on peronal opinion. If you want to know the most popular, that would be Overleaf, but you requiere an internet connection to use it.

Comment: there is a new solution since this week: https://texlive.net/

Comment: Overleaf is the best by far

Comment: For https://www.learnlatex.org, 'we' (David Carlisle mainly) looked at several online services before developing our own (see https://www.learnlatex.org/en/help for detail). However, the requirements there may well be different from yours: without some objective way to judge, it's hard to what the 'right' answer is here.

Comment: @NIckBennett overleaf is very good at what it does but it is mainly aimed at interactive online editing not so much as returning generated pdf via an API, compare for example the two buttons below the example at https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-03  one uses an API to return a PDF to the same page, the overleaf one opens a new tab in a new overleaf project. Hard to say which is better as the behaviour is just fundamentally different.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310507/any-latex-web-services-with-an-api

Comment: Check out this thread, it may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310507/any-latex-web-services-with-an-api

Answer (score 2):

Overleaf would be a great choice I think.

- It allows you to sync with github or dropbox any change you make in your dropbox folder containing a project is immediately reflected online. Is is very convenient if you have figures, just edit them in your dropbox and you will see the changes next time you compile on overleaf.
- It also allows to collaborate simultaneously on the same project as you would do in a Google doc and track the history.
- It integrates with Mendeley which is very convenient to manage your references.

Finally, they have a great support team if you have issue with your projects.

I have to say that I have no interest in Overleaf. I am just a very satisfied user. :)

**[Edit]**

Some of the features I mentioned indeed require a paid plan. However you can get the first two for free just by having "friends" that subscribes on the platform (https://www.overleaf.com/user/bonus)

Comment: But several of the options you cite  here are for paid subscription (notice that this is not a criticism for overleaf, services that have a cost should be paid to make them sustainable in the long term)

Comment: Yes you are right, I did not see the free mention in the question. I updated my answer to reflect on your comment :)